# How to stop adding and removing an object?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm making a like button for my app and I want a way to make it so that it doesn't crash if you click the button before it's done saving. I've tried many things but they don't seem to work, but basically what's happening is the app crashes if it isn't done adding or removing the userId...

```
func like(sender: UIButton) {

    var buttonPosition: CGPoint = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.table)

    var indexPath: NSIndexPath = self.table.indexPathForRowAtPoint(buttonPosition)!

    testConnection()

    var post = posts[indexPath.row]

    var postCell = PostCell()

    if sender.currentTitle == "Unlike" {

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

            sender.setTitle("Like", forState: .Normal)

            post.removeObject(PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!, forKey: "likers")

            self.liked[indexPath.row] = true

            self.table.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)

            post.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success, error) -> Void in

            })

        }
    } else {

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

            sender.setTitle("Unlike", forState: .Normal)

            post.addUniqueObject(PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!, forKey: "likers")

            self.liked[indexPath.row] = true

            self.table.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)

            post.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success, error) -> Void in

            })
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my crash log...

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException',        reason: 'Operation is invalid after previous operation.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010821ec65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000107eb5bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   AppName                               0x0000000105251e39 -[PFAddUniqueOperation applyToValue:forKey:ofObject:] + 0
    3   AppName                               0x000000010526f9be -[PFObject(Private) performOperation:forKey:] + 287
    4   AppName                               0x00000001052785a6 -[PFObject addUniqueObjectsFromArray:forKey:] + 126
    5   AppName                               0x000000010527850c -[PFObject addUniqueObject:forKey:] + 126
    6   AppName                               0x0000000105205348 _TTSf2n_d_i_n_d_i___TFFC5AppName4Feed4likeFS0_FCSo8UIButtonT_U0_FT_T_ + 968
    7   AppName                               0x00000001051f2347 _TTRXFo__dT__XFdCb__dT__ + 39
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000108acd186 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000108aec614 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000108ad4a1c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1664
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001081861f9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108147dcb __CFRunLoopRun + 2043
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108147366 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    14  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001098e1a3e GSEventRunModal + 161
    15  UIKit                               0x0000000106a528c0 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    16  AppName                               0x000000010520da57 main + 135
    17  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000108b21145 start + 1
    18  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: Where it is crashing or what is your crash log?

Comment: @DharmeshKheni I just added my crash log and I believe it crashes because it is trying to run 2 things on the same thread.

Comment: What are you doing in `testConnection()` method?

Comment: @DharmeshKheni Oh yeah sorry for the bad formatting

Comment: @DharmeshKheni I'm checking to see if the user has internet.

Comment: Just comment it and try.

Comment: That function is too big to properly debug. Refactor it first then you'll make it easier to find where the problem is.

Comment: why dont you disable button at the begining of the like method and enable it back again when you finish all the processing for examp in the post.saveInBackgroundWithBlock

Comment: @Fogmeister I was able to figure out the problem and that is because I can't add or remove an object of the same cell while saving, so it crashes. I'm trying to find a way around that problem that isn't disabling the button while it's saving.

Comment: @DharmeshKheni Just tried that and still no luck.

Comment: @AntonijoDev Yeah I did that but it looks ugly.

Comment: @JohnDoe , which is source object for the table view ?

Comment: @karthik The source object for the table view is just called table.

Comment: @JohnDoe, I am asking about the object array that you have used to load your table view , what is that post object ?

Comment: @karthik Oh sorry. The posts object array contains all of the posts from Parse.

Comment: @JohnDoe, if Post is the source why you remove the object when Unlike is clicked , John this should be model inconsistency in the table view , I cannot understand what you really want to achieve , please post some screenshot of your app , and explain your code (what the variable does in a comment ) so that we can identify the issue easily .